# Access Sony QX100 video stream with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, sony, ip-camera, sony-camera-api

I want to access the camera's video stream with OpenCV.

Doing so, I connected the camera via WLAN with my Win7 PC. Further, Maybe a possible way to go is by http://ip:port/resource'). I tried e.g. http://10.0.0.1:65534/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=123456&resolution=32" but did not succeed.

Does anyone know the necessary credentials {IP, port, user, password, etc..} for this specific camera's live video stream?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Camera Remote API:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Specifically check out the LiveView API.  Should allow you to capture the live video stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found a tutorial (http://www.dpreview.com/articles/3727076886/sony-camera-developer-api-403-forbidden-for-undocumented-apis-) which helped me a lot finding ip:port.

Comment: next hurdle/question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346788/run-sonys-cameraremotesampleapp-in-ecplise