# Run Sony's CameraRemoteSampleApp in ecplise

Tags: android, eclipse, sony-camera-api

I am trying to bring up the sample code of sony's remote camera API with eclipse following this tutorial (https://developer.sony.com/2013/11/29/how-to-develop-an-app-using-the-camera-remote-api-2/) but won't work. Could you provide a step-by-step tutorial please?

try #1:
1.: File->New->create a new Android App Project
2.: Import->"File System"->from directory "..\CameraRemoteAPIbeta_SDK_1.50\CameraRemoteSampleApp\Android" into the new Android App Project (Option: overwrite existing resource without warning=yes)

try #2:
1.: Create empty project
2.: Copy folders "res" and "src" and file manifest into this empty project

Both tries ended up with a long list of errors, e.g.: "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! ..by reinstalling v4 and v7 support libraries!